# each time iframe create new iframe when i called iframe parent page

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I have client.jsp page i put following iframe inside it

```
<IFRAME SRC="<%=filterPath%>" width="100%" height="1811px"  id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

In `client.jsp` i have link to call other page and from that page i again redirect on client.jsp using following code

```
<a href="client.jsp">redirect</a>
```

When i look viewsource for the same i found two iframe and code is like

```
<iframe>
   <iframe>

   <iframe>
</iframe>
```

Each time i called client.jsp from other page it creates new iframe 
How i rid from this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your link is inside of iframe and you load into iframe new client.jsp with other iframe - you will get this. This is ok. Just put at head of iframe this:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

or specify for every link target="_parent":

```
<a href="your_href" target="_parent">your link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the page in the main window, instead of IFRAME, when redirect is clicked.

You can achieve this by using the following code :

```
<a target="_parent" href="client.jsp">redirect</a>
```